# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas from GKE pod

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, ip, kubernetes-pod, mongodb-atlas

I have a pod running on Google Cloud Kubernetes and I have a MongoDB cluster running on Atlas.
The issue is quite simple:

**If I allow IP from ANYWHERE on Atlas MongoDB, I can connect. 
If I add the IP of the pod (so not from ANYWHERE anymore), it doesn't work.**

I also tried locally and from a docker running locally as well, it works.

I got the IP (YY.YYY.YYY.YY) of my pod using:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Emixam23:plop-service emixam23$ kubectl get services
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                           AGE
polop-service  LoadBalancer   XX.XX.X.XXX   YY.YYY.YYY.YY   ZZZZZ:32633/TCP,ZZZZZ:32712/TCP   172m
kubernetes     ClusterIP      XX.X.X.X      <none>          443/TCP                           3h24m
```

But by the behavior I get.. I feel like this EXTERNAL-IP isn't the IP from where my requests are sent from.

Can anyone explain to me what can be the issue?

Comment: I am running into similar issue. One of the pods which is associated with Ingress loadbalancer is working but another pods running on same node is not able to access it. The pods that is not able to access mongodb Atlas is just a cronjob pod.

Comment: I guess it’s because the requests aren’t sent by the pod itself, can’t remember but yes, the requests might be passing by another IP of your Kubernetes cluster

Comment: Thanks for the reply, added each and every ip range of Kubernetes cluster but still not working. No idea if its because need access to some email sending protocols too :D

Answer (score 1):

The IP exposed to Mongo Atlas should be Internet accessible IP (or called it, public IP).

Normally it should be the net gateway IPs (or proxy server's IPs, if you go with proxy).

One quick way to check the IP by running below command in pods

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

If your pod doesn't support this command, you can `kubectl exec -ti <pod_name> -- sh` in it and install this command.

**Remember**: normally the IPs are not only one, there should be 3 or more public facing IPs via net gateway, you need find them all and add to Mongo Atlas whitelists

Comment: The IP I put is actually the load balancer one and the requests are made from the pod itself.. Which have another IP, so mistake on my end. However, it means that each pod for each start would have a new IP, which is definitely not manageable, doesn’t it?

Comment: the IP for load balancer is ingress IP, not egress IPs. What you need is the pod's egress IPs, they will be used to connect to Mongo Atlas.

Comment: How can I get them? (Ingress IPs list) Do you need more details regarding my service.yaml or whatever related to my pods?

Comment: k8s will most probably use interface public ip of the node where pod is currently running so use `kubectl get pod <podname> -owide` to identify node where the pod got scheduled and later use `kubectl get no <node_name> -owide` to identify node's external ip.